# Lambda function inconsistently updating DynamoDB table

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

## Overview

I'm trying to create a row on another table within my DynamoDB upon the creation of a row on the Profile table.

The lambda function is called every time a profile is created, however I can't seem to reliably create the row on the other table. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

I've also noticed that the row will sometimes get created when I remove the profile row that it was supposed to be associated to, and sometimes it will also succeed if I create several profiles at once.

## My best guess so far..

My best guess for this is that the function is getting hung up and taking much longer to finish then expected, or there is some type of queue system that I'm not aware of?

## What I've tried

I've used await to wait for promises to finish, I've also removed await all together, doesn't seem to make any difference.

I've also tried catching any exceptions, when it silently fails (which doesn't seem to catch anything).

## Code I'm Using

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

/**
 * addWhatImLookingFor model to the user's profile
 * @param record the current record being processed
 * @param context the context
 */
async function addWhatImLookingFor(record, context, profileId) {
    try {
        const newId = context.awsRequestId;
        const dateTime = new Date().toISOString();

        const params = {
            TableName: process.env.WHAT_IM_LOOKING_FOR_TABLE,
            Item: {
                id: newId,
                __typename: process.env.WHAT_IM_LOOKING_FOR_TYPENAME,
                createdAt: dateTime,
                updatedAt: dateTime,
            },
        };
        docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Failed creation");
                context.fail();
            }
            else {
                console.log(`Record creation happened at: ${new Date().toISOString()} with params:${JSON.stringify(params)}, and with record: ${JSON.stringify(record)}`);
                context.succeed();

            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

/**
 * processes a record in the list of event.Records
 * @param record
 * @param context
 */
async function processRecord(record, context) {
    if ('NewImage' in record.dynamodb) {
        if (record.dynamodb.NewImage.__typename.S === 'Profile') {
            switch (record['eventName']) {
                case 'INSERT':
                    addWhatImLookingFor(record, context, record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.S);
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Handler for this lambda function.
 */
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    // Processing each record in the event in async
    event.Records.map(record => processRecord(record, context));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by ensuring that I was returning all promises

## Updated Code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

/**
 * add WhatImLookingFor model to the user's profile
 * @param record the current record being processed
 * @param context the context
 */
async function addWhatImLookingFor(record, context, profileId) {
    try {
        const newId = context.awsRequestId;
        const dateTime = new Date().toISOString();

        const params = {
            TableName: process.env.WHAT_IM_LOOKING_FOR_TABLE,
            Item: {
                id: newId,
                __typename: process.env.WHAT_IM_LOOKING_FOR_TYPENAME,
                createdAt: dateTime,
                updatedAt: dateTime,
            },
        };
        const promise = docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Failed creation");
                context.fail();
            }
            else {
                console.log(`Record creation happened at: ${new Date().toISOString()} with params:${JSON.stringify(params)}, and with record: ${JSON.stringify(record)}`);
                context.succeed();
            }
        }).promise();
        return promise;
    }
    catch (err) {
        // Attempting to catch any silent errors, atm not catching anything.
        console.log(err);
        return -1;
    }
}

/**
 * processes a record in the list of event.Records
 * @param record
 * @param context
 */
async function processRecord(record, context) {
    let ret_value;
    if ('NewImage' in record.dynamodb) {
        if (record.dynamodb.NewImage.__typename.S === 'Profile') {
            switch (record['eventName']) {
                case 'INSERT':
                    ret_value = addWhatImLookingFor(record, context, record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.S);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret_value;
}


/**
 * Handler for this lambda function.
 */
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    // Processing each record in the event in async
    const promises = event.Records.map(record => processRecord(record, context));
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('Successfully completed all promises'));
};
```